# Why isn't MySQL using an index for this query when it uses one for 99% of other queries of an identical form?

Tags: mysql, sql, indexing

I have a database which I make a lot of queries to like this:

```
mysql> explain     SELECT  time, user, x, y, z, type, action
        FROM  co_block
        WHERE  time >= 1642497664
          AND  wid = 4
          AND  x <= -7650
          AND  x >= -7651;

+----+-------------+----------+------------+-------+---------------+------+---------+------+---------+----------+-----------------------+
| id | select_type | table    | partitions | type  | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows    | filtered | Extra                 |
+----+-------------+----------+------------+-------+---------------+------+---------+------+---------+----------+-----------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | co_block | NULL       | range | wid           | wid  | 10      | NULL | 3940334 |    33.33 | Using index condition |
+----+-------------+----------+------------+-------+---------------+------+---------+------+---------+----------+-----------------------+
```

This query returns 101 rows in 0.7 seconds.

Almost all of them return very quickly, but occasionally I run into one that takes an eternity, like this almost-identical query which differs only in the X range that is searched.

```
mysql> explain SELECT time, user, x, y, z, type, action FROM co_block WHERE time >= 1642497664 AND wid = 4 AND x <= -7651 AND x >= -7652;
+----+-------------+----------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+-----------+----------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table    | partitions | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows      | filtered | Extra       |
+----+-------------+----------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+-----------+----------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | co_block | NULL       | ALL  | wid           | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 116322801 |     3.59 | Using where |
+----+-------------+----------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+-----------+----------+-------------+
```

This query returns 85 rows after a painful 68 seconds.

If I use FORCE INDEX to force the use of the index, the query returns in only 1.2 seconds, so it obviously can be used and to great benefit, and indeed MySQL seems to actually use it in 99.99% of the queries of this sort that I make.  So why is it choosing not to use the index in this case?

The "explain" of the FORCE INDEX queries, in case they're insightful:

```
mysql> explain SELECT time, user, x, y, z, type, action FROM co_block FORCE INDEX (`wid`) WHERE time >= 1642497664 AND wid = 4 AND x <= -7650 AND x >= -7651;
+----+-------------+----------+------------+-------+---------------+------+---------+------+---------+----------+-----------------------+
| id | select_type | table    | partitions | type  | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows    | filtered | Extra                 |
+----+-------------+----------+------------+-------+---------------+------+---------+------+---------+----------+-----------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | co_block | NULL       | range | wid           | wid  | 10      | NULL | 3940334 |    33.33 | Using index condition |
+----+-------------+----------+------------+-------+---------------+------+---------+------+---------+----------+-----------------------+
1 row in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)

mysql> explain SELECT time, user, x, y, z, type, action FROM co_block FORCE INDEX (`wid`) WHERE time >= 1642497664 AND wid = 4 AND x <= -7651 AND x >= -7652;
+----+-------------+----------+------------+-------+---------------+------+---------+------+----------+----------+-----------------------+
| id | select_type | table    | partitions | type  | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows     | filtered | Extra                 |
+----+-------------+----------+------------+-------+---------------+------+---------+------+----------+----------+-----------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | co_block | NULL       | range | wid           | wid  | 10      | NULL | 12543806 |    33.33 | Using index condition |
+----+-------------+----------+------------+-------+---------------+------+---------+------+----------+----------+-----------------------+
1 row in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)
```

Table definition:

```
CREATE TABLE `co_block` (
  `rowid` bigint NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `time` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `user` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `wid` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `x` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `y` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `z` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `type` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `data` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `meta` blob,
  `blockdata` blob,
  `action` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `rolled_back` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`rowid`),
  KEY `wid` (`wid`,`x`,`z`,`time`),
  KEY `user` (`user`,`time`),
  KEY `type` (`type`,`time`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=252511481 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb3
```

Index info:

```
mysql> show index from co_block;
+----------+------------+----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+---------+------------+
| Table    | Non_unique | Key_name | Seq_in_index | Column_name | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment | Visible | Expression |
+----------+------------+----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+---------+------------+
| co_block |          0 | PRIMARY  |            1 | rowid       | A         |   116288328 |     NULL |   NULL |      | BTREE      |         |               | YES     | NULL       |
| co_block |          1 | wid      |            1 | wid         | A         |         886 |     NULL |   NULL | YES  | BTREE      |         |               | YES     | NULL       |
| co_block |          1 | wid      |            2 | x           | A         |      135141 |     NULL |   NULL | YES  | BTREE      |         |               | YES     | NULL       |
| co_block |          1 | wid      |            3 | z           | A         |    22393332 |     NULL |   NULL | YES  | BTREE      |         |               | YES     | NULL       |
| co_block |          1 | wid      |            4 | time        | A         |    71268960 |     NULL |   NULL | YES  | BTREE      |         |               | YES     | NULL       |
| co_block |          1 | user     |            1 | user        | A         |       49756 |     NULL |   NULL | YES  | BTREE      |         |               | YES     | NULL       |
| co_block |          1 | user     |            2 | time        | A         |    13558248 |     NULL |   NULL | YES  | BTREE      |         |               | YES     | NULL       |
| co_block |          1 | type     |            1 | type        | A         |       33126 |     NULL |   NULL | YES  | BTREE      |         |               | YES     | NULL       |
| co_block |          1 | type     |            2 | time        | A         |    28455380 |     NULL |   NULL | YES  | BTREE      |         |               | YES     | NULL       |
+----------+------------+----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+---------+------------+
```

Likely irrelevant notes:

The actual queries I'm making are grabbing 16x16 chunks by specifying both an X range and a Z range, but in trying to debug the problem myself, the Z range specified doesn't seem to be relevant to the problem, so I removed it from the queries.

In one of the many "why isn't MySQL using my index" questions I read, the problem was that the condition specified by the WHERE clause included almost all of the records.  This made me wonder if the problem might be the order of the "x >= -7652" and "x <= -7651" conditions, as the first would include almost all of the records in the database, and only the second actually eliminates most of them.  So I reversed the order of these two conditions, but it made no difference.  I also tried using BETWEEN to specify the range but that too had no effect.

Though perhaps only due to insufficient effort to find an example case, it seems to be required that there is both an "x >=" and an "x <=" condition.

The time constrain is not required but I included it above because otherwise there is much more data returned by the queries.  Here are the "explain" queries with the time constraint removed:

```
mysql> explain SELECT time, user, x, y, z, type, action FROM co_block WHERE wid = 4 AND x <= -7651 AND x >= -7652;
+----+-------------+----------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+-----------+----------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table    | partitions | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows      | filtered | Extra       |
+----+-------------+----------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+-----------+----------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | co_block | NULL       | ALL  | wid           | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 116325588 |    10.78 | Using where |
+----+-------------+----------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+-----------+----------+-------------+
1 row in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)

mysql> explain SELECT time, user, x, y, z, type, action FROM co_block WHERE wid = 4 AND x <= -7650 AND x >= -7651;
+----+-------------+----------+------------+-------+---------------+------+---------+------+---------+----------+-----------------------+
| id | select_type | table    | partitions | type  | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows    | filtered | Extra                 |
+----+-------------+----------+------------+-------+---------------+------+---------+------+---------+----------+-----------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | co_block | NULL       | range | wid           | wid  | 10      | NULL | 3940334 |   100.00 | Using index condition |
+----+-------------+----------+------------+-------+---------------+------+---------+------+---------+----------+-----------------------+
1 row in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)
```

Query results requested by nnichols:

```
mysql> SELECT COUNT(*) FROM co_block FORCE INDEX (wid) WHERE wid = 4 AND x <= -7650 AND x >= -7651;
+----------+
| COUNT(*) |
+----------+
|  2958623 |
+----------+
1 row in set (0.86 sec)

mysql> explain SELECT COUNT(*) FROM co_block FORCE INDEX (wid) WHERE wid = 4 AND x <= -7650 AND x >= -7651;
+----+-------------+----------+------------+-------+---------------+------+---------+------+---------+----------+--------------------------+
| id | select_type | table    | partitions | type  | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows    | filtered | Extra                    |
+----+-------------+----------+------------+-------+---------------+------+---------+------+---------+----------+--------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | co_block | NULL       | range | wid           | wid  | 10      | NULL | 3940334 |   100.00 | Using where; Using index |
+----+-------------+----------+------------+-------+---------------+------+---------+------+---------+----------+--------------------------+
1 row in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT COUNT(*) FROM co_block FORCE INDEX (wid) WHERE wid = 4 AND x <= -7651 AND x >= -7652;
+----------+
| COUNT(*) |
+----------+
|  8982424 |
+----------+
1 row in set (2.38 sec)

mysql> explain SELECT COUNT(*) FROM co_block FORCE INDEX (wid) WHERE wid = 4 AND x <= -7651 AND x >= -7652;
+----+-------------+----------+------------+-------+---------------+------+---------+------+----------+----------+--------------------------+
| id | select_type | table    | partitions | type  | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows     | filtered | Extra                    |
+----+-------------+----------+------------+-------+---------------+------+---------+------+----------+----------+--------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | co_block | NULL       | range | wid           | wid  | 10      | NULL | 12543806 |   100.00 | Using where; Using index |
+----+-------------+----------+------------+-------+---------------+------+---------+------+----------+----------+--------------------------+
1 row in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: And what happens if you run the `SELECT * FROM (SELECT time, user, x, y, z, type, action FROM co_block WHERE wid = 4) t WHERE x <= -7651 AND x >= -7652;` query?

Comment: @RadimBača That query also does not use the index, and takes 70 seconds to execute.

Comment: @nnichols I have added those results to the end of my question.

Comment: Sorry, no "smoking gun", at least not to my eyes. It looks like in this case MySQL is determining that the index is not selective enough to be useful, hence opting for the scan. Does your dataset reside in memory? Does it fit in the buffer pool or is InnoDB constantly swapping?

Comment: I have been trying a few things but my test dataset is tiny (~4.7M rows) compared to your data. Using `x IN (-7651, -7650)` gave the same explain (except rows) as `AND x <= -7650 AND x >= -7651`, but it was much faster (0.001s instead of 0.01s). I don't understand why, but I would be interested to know whether you experience similar.

Comment: @nnichols The database is 35 GB and this particular table is 23 GB.  The innodb_buffer_pool_size (which I was previously unaware of) is 128 MB.  The internet tells me it should be much larger, but I only have enough RAM to go as far as 3 GB, yet that seems to be enough.  After running the faster query (which I assume forces it to load the index into memory) it will then start using the index for the slower query too.  If I then reduce innodb_buffer_pool_size to the original size, the original behavior returns.  So the problem does seem to be triggered by the pool size being too small.

Comment: @nnichols (continuing) WRT your second question, with the original 128 MB pool size, it seems to essentially make no difference (maybe it's only 66 seconds instead of 70) but with the larger 3 GB pool size I see the reverse, with the IN query taking 1.2 seconds while the <= AND >= query takes only 0.33 seconds.

Comment: Interesting! What version of MySQL are you running, and on what OS? My test dataset is still smaller (~50M rows, 9GB data + indices) and I have plenty of RAM so it sits comfortably in memory. It still returns in under 0.02s for all queries of that structure. What are your min and max values for wid, x, y, z and time? Is the distribution of values in these fields quite even? Do you have nulls in those fields? Using the smaller integer types where applicable and only allowing nulls if actually needed makes a significant difference to the size and performance of the indices.

Comment: If you have only 4GB of RAM, 3G may be too much for the buffer pool -- it could lead to swapping, which is terrible for performance.  Stop at 2G for a 4G machine (or VM).

Comment: Version is 8.0.27-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 on Linux Mint 20.2.  The database belongs to a Minecraft plugin that records everything that players do.  wid values are mostly 4 but also 5 or 6, x and z generally go from about -8000 to +8000 but the edges are fuzzy (actual minimum x is -8417) and the data tends to center around certain locations in the (x, z) coordinate space as players build towns.  time goes from 1579861381 (Jan 2020) to 1643204435 (now).  time, user, wid, x, y, z, type, action, are never NULL.  Data is rarely read so 1 second reads are fine but 70 seconds is too much.

Comment: @RickJames It actually has 16 GB but most is consumed by the Minecraft server itself which will die if it has less than 8 GB.  The `free` command showed 5 GB left and, being well aware of how the whole system will crash and burn if it's ever forced to use swap, I decided to only give it 3 GB.  I'm not sure how the index works but I'm guessing it is at least 2 GB since that's what the fields add up to.  We plan to upgrade the RAM eventually, at which point I'll probably make the pool size 8 GB so it can hopefully keep this index and the ones belonging to the smaller tables loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Add these two indexes and see if things improve:

```
INDEX(wid, x, time),
INDEX(wid, time, x)
```

Also, run this once:

```
ANALYZE TABLE co_block;
```

How big is the table compared to `innodb_buffer_pool_size`?  If quite big, then think about whether some of the `INTs` (4 bytes each) can be shrunk to smaller datatypes.

This might help, too:

```
ORDER BY x, time
```

**More**

`innodb_buffer_pool_size` should be about 70% of available RAM, not the old default of 128M.  That serves as a cache for the data and/or indexes.  So, when running several related queries, the first may be slow, and the rest may be faster.  Run a query twice to make sure the timing is not biased by the caching.

Comment: And don't allow nulls unless really needed.

Comment: "ORDER BY x, time"  and ANALYZE TABLE had no effect.  Adding the indexes did speed up the query.  (I then removed them as I don't think they should be necessary.)

The table is 23 GB and the pool size is 128 MB.  I increased the pool size to 3 GB and that sped up the slower query, but only after running the faster query first, as if MySQL decides to use the index for the slower query only if the index is already in memory.

Comment: I did not try changing the data types, as the table primarily belongs to a Minecraft plugin and I'm not sure how it might respond to that.  Also, doing so seems more like a potential work-around than a diagnostic measure, but at this point I want to know why the problem exists more than I want to fix it.  (and increasing the pool size seems like the best work-around since it probably needs to be much larger anyway)

Comment: @Coleo - I addressed some of your Comments in an addition to my Answer.  Was the buffer_pool_size different on the servers?

Comment: @RickJames I'm not sure what you're asking but I did some more testing and it does seem that I just have to run any similar query (even the slow one) and then after that the slow query becomes fast.  However, the EXPLAIN shows that it won't use the index until such a query has been performed and then after that it begins showing that it will, so it doesn't appear to simply be a caching issue, but rather something makes MySQL change it's mind about whether it should use the index for that query.

Comment: @RickJames After going from 128 MB to 3 GB, the faster query is 0.36 seconds on the first run vs. 0.32 on subsequent runs.  With the same starting conditions, the slower query is 67.31 seconds on the first run vs. 1.81 on the second run and then 0.98 on subsequent runs.

Comment: @Coleo - The added indexes, plus the data type changes by nnichols will give you some breathing room -- perhaps avoiding the need for more RAM.

Answer (score 0):

As already discussed in the comments and mentioned by @RickJames, you really should update the datatypes to better fit the data.  I would suggest starting with -

```sql
ALTER TABLE `co_block` 
    CHANGE COLUMN `time` `time` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL, /* 5 => 4 bytes per index entry */
    CHANGE COLUMN `wid` `wid` TINYINT NOT NULL,        /* 5 => 1 byte */
    CHANGE COLUMN `x` `x` SMALLINT NOT NULL,           /* 5 => 2 bytes */
    CHANGE COLUMN `z` `z` SMALLINT NOT NULL;           /* 5 => 2 bytes */
```

This will reduce your `wid` index from 20 bytes => 9 bytes per row; less than half the size. Assuming similar changes can be made to all the integer fields, your space saving on both the data and index will be considerable. That reduction in size will also lead to improved performance.

If you are concerned about possible impact on the plugin then do some digging online or speak to the developer. Do you need to retain all the data? Should you implement a purge routine to remove data older than x months?

**NULLness in InnoDB**

I built a very small table and populated it with 50M rows -

```sql
CREATE TABLE `test_null_index` (
  `id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `tiny` TINYINT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Running in ultra-paranoid mode, I ran an OPTIMIZE and ANALYZE before grabbing the stats after each table change - no index, with index allowing nulls and with index not null. I then re-ran with just 5M rows. Here are the results -

| **TABLE_NAME** | **TABLE_ROWS** | **AVG_ROW_LENGTH** | **DATA_LENGTH** | **INDEX_LENGTH** | **DATA_FREE** |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| test_null_index | 49926120 | 30 | 1509933056 | 0 | 2097152 |
| test_null_index | 49926120 | 30 | 1509933056 | 664780800 | 5242880 |
| test_null_index | 49929637 | 28 | 1447018496 | 606044160 | 3145728 |
| test_null_index | 4992899 | 29 | 145358848 | 0 | 5242880 |
| test_null_index | 4992899 | 29 | 145358848 | 61407232 | 5242880 |
| test_null_index | 4992975 | 27 | 139067392 | 55115776 | 2097152 |

| **TABLE_ROWS** | **INDEX_LEN_NULL** | **INDEX_LEN_NOT_NULL** | **INDEX_LEN_DIFF** | **AVG_DIFF_PER_ROW** |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 50000000 | 664780800 | 606044160 | 58736640 | 1.1747328 |
| 5000000 | 61407232 | 55115776 | 6291456 | 1.2582912 |

Looks like NULLness taking an extra byte in InnoDB is a thing.

Comment: I have not found real proof that NULLness takes an extra byte in InnoDB; do you have a reference (other than `EXPLAIN`)?

Comment: No real proof. I will try optimizing my tablespace before and after adding/removing nullness to one of the columns and see if the size difference roughly correlates with the 1 byte per index row.

Comment: Since data is allocated in 16KB blocks and 1MB(?) extents, I suspect a 1 byte change in a column might not reliably show up with your experiment.  Anyway, I am interested to hear how it goes.  Perhaps a 2-col, million-row table where the non-primary-key column is `TINYINT` (NULL vs NOT NULL)` might have the resolution needed.

Comment: I did purge some data a few months ago.  It turns out that the bulk of the data comes from in-game machines that repeatedly place and then remove blocks.  By simply removing all pairs of records that add up to a null result, more than half of the records were deleted.  We do expect to have to do a time based purge at some point but it is nice to be able to see who built what so we're waiting until we're forced to make that decision.  I'll probably end up reducing the field sizes before that happens but I'll have to do some testing to make sure nothing will go wrong when I do.

Comment: @Coleo - If you decide to delete _all_ data older than some date, then partitioning is recommended:  [_Partition_](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/partitionmaint)

Comment: @RickJames - Your thoughts on the NULLness stats?